# Provide user options in Electron's `showSaveDialog()`

Tags: save, electron

I was wondering if anybody had manage to suss out a way of adding options to the `dialog.showSaveDialog()`? I want to achieve something like Adobe illustrator does with artboards...

[image]

I've checked the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) and cannot see anything that would suggest that you could so I'm either missing something or it's simply not possible (hopefully the former).

Thanks!

Comment: afaik, Electron does not support that. Adobe likely subclassed the OSX dialog code to add those custom properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look to be possible in the current version (v8)